# Error when creating model version on GCP AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am trying to create a version of the model and link it to my exported Tensorflow model. however it gives me the following error : `health probe timeout: generic::unavailable: The fetch failed with status 3 and reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx Check the url is available and that authentication parameters are specified correctly`.

I have made my SaveModel directory **public** and have attached **service-xxxxxxxxxxxx@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com** to my bucket with **Storage Legacy Bucket Reader**. My service account **service-xxxxxxxxxxxx@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com** has role **ML Engine Admin and Storage Admin**. The bucket and ml-engine are part of the **same project** and region **us-central1**. I am initialising the model version with the following config:

```
Python version: 2.7
Framework: TensorFlow
Framework version: 1.12.3
Runtime version: 1.12
Machine type: n1-highmem-2
Accelerator: Nvidia Tesla K-80 
Accelerator count: 1
```

Note : I used python 2.7 for training and runtime version 1.12

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify Saved model is valid by using CLI.
Check that Serving tag-sets are available in your saved model, use the [SavedModel CLI](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model):

```
saved_model_cli show --dir <your model directory>
```